# upload terminates before 'before unload' response is received

Tags: javascript, jquery, file-upload, onbeforeunload

I have this 'before unload' warning which alerts when an ajax file upload is in progress and the user navigates away before it has finished. But (in chrome and safari) if the user uses 'back' or 'forward' to navigate away the upload is automatically ended before they even have a chance to click 'stay on this page'. at first I thought this might be an unpreventable feature of chrome, but I did a test on gmail. I attached a file and clicked 'back' before it finished uploading. I then clicked 'stay on this page when the warning came up' and it just continued as normal. Anyone have any Idea how to overcome this problem? Thanks

```
$(window).bind('beforeunload', function() {
   if (stillUploading) {
        return 'Your files are still uploading';
    }
});
```

Comment: how are you doing the file upload?

Comment: with ajax httprequest

Comment: you might test your scenario with a jQuery uploader plugin (such as [Uploadify](http://www.uploadify.com/) or [Fine Uploader](http://fineuploader.com/)).  The uploaders use one of the following techniques: AJAX, hidden `<iframe>`, or flash.  So you could test if hidden `<iframe>` or flash might get around the issue.